# Json is not responding

Tags: android, arrays, json, flutter, dart

i am trying to initialize json data in my widget but for some reason, it is not responding. i am pretty new to dealing with json called locally and this is one of them. i have already done all the necessary things like creating the file to put the data and passing it through the pubspec. still it is not responding. here is the json data

```
[
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce55270d648e9a5248a",
      "index":0,
      "guid":"58e73438-27fa-48bf-8127-ff4e42beaac5",
      "isActive":true,
      "price":"$252.77",
      "name":"James Lewis Blue Ledis",
      "type":"dress",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1539008835657-9e8e9680c956?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce573d4e1ce44e5a5a9",
      "index":1,
      "guid":"e1d93cfe-b15a-4969-97e0-3b6b9ae967d0",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$289.88",
      "name":"Blue FLower Shoe",
      "type":"apparel",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543163521-1bf539c55dd2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce522bd392da7b43d2e",
      "index":2,
      "guid":"0ee56032-db50-44c3-9234-5e213b8fde22",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$452.81",
      "name":"Yellow Blight Bag",
      "type":"bag",
      "image":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/934673/pexels-photo-934673.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
      "recommended":true
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce5fdf98a105a5c14cb",
      "index":3,
      "guid":"fee6217c-ee7f-4e3e-91cc-24dfd91d6cfc",
      "isActive":true,
      "price":"$244.91",
      "name":"Black meter dress",
      "type":"dress",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550639525-c97d455acf70?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=726&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce5036de010a96ab185",
      "index":4,
      "guid":"2d9e8b22-90c1-4979-b904-2cc164626e10",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$335.17",
      "name":"Dynamic Pink Lobre",
      "type":"bag",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566150905458-1bf1fc113f0d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1171&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce52e2a60eed71c79b6",
      "index":5,
      "guid":"32db02a5-a12d-4f3e-a601-787211734ab1",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$414.69",
      "name":"Gucci Flems Onyx",
      "type":"bag",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548036328-c9fa89d128fa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce52f14c39bb8366650",
      "index":6,
      "recommended":true,
      "guid":"1a0c388c-2ac7-4a49-85ba-50b12bc08f28",
      "isActive":true,
      "price":"$293.63",
      "name":"705 California",
      "type":"apparel",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618354691229-88d47f285158?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=715&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce56b57e56f54676302",
      "index":7,
      "guid":"956527b1-c9d8-4c18-a6ef-e4b1dcd76640",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$293.57",
      "name":"Mid-week flavors",
      "type":"apparel",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560769629-975ec94e6a86?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=764&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce56c0ed15b28297895",
      "index":8,
      "guid":"119db62a-eaba-493f-b73a-5dcba04b69c1",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$348.63",
      "name":"Hermes Coysx",
      "type":"bag",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594223274512-ad4803739b7c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=757&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce58d2cbb1e636f1829",
      "index":9,
      "guid":"40011d30-d06d-4a72-b119-0826dc79c138",
      "isActive":true,
      "price":"$337.91",
      "name":"Kirsten Gilliam",
      "type":"dress",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543163521-1bf539c55dd2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce5713679af9a884699",
      "index":10,
      "guid":"f5dbfba4-fbe2-475b-98fc-36ff42daad91",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$436.62",
      "recommended":true,
      "name":"Outcast white",
      "type":"t-shirt",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527719327859-c6ce80353573?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=764&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce5578fa1d92624204f",
      "index":11,
      "guid":"805df707-3833-4e5f-9e09-0c59053750cb",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$493.15",
      "name":"Peace Skull",
      "type":"t-shirt",
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503341504253-dff4815485f1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce5bd29b6bd570aef00",
      "index":12,
      "guid":"32e75d5c-ea59-4c23-8d85-29dd37040a7d",
      "isActive":false,
      "price":"$350.71",
      "name":"Louis Vuiton Brown bag",
      "type":"bag",
      "image":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/3661622/pexels-photo-3661622.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
   },
   {
      "_id":"636e0ce505794be5900eb9ad",
      "index":13,
      "guid":"44aa2a9a-e1c9-4004-b681-ce246e5a8ee4",
      "isActive":true,
      "price":"$271.21",
      "name":"Impulso Supreme",
      "type":"t-shirt",
      "recommended":true,
      "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1627933540891-1fb6a397c89b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=764&q=80"
   }
]
```

and this is where it is being called

```
class ExploreCollections extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExploreCollections({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExploreCollections> createState() => _ExploreCollectionsState();
}

class _ExploreCollectionsState extends State<ExploreCollections> {
  final List _items = [];

  Future<void> readJson() async{
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/model/clothes.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _items.shuffle();
    super.initState();
  }

  int _activeIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _images = [
    Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/images/image 10.png'),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 55.0, top: 230),
          child: Text(
            'Luxury \n   Fashion \n &Accessories'.toUpperCase(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Bodoni',
                fontSize: 40,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.grey.shade700
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 400.0),
          child: Center(
            child:SvgPicture.asset('assets/iconImages/Button.svg'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/images/leeloo.jpeg'),
      ],
    ),
    Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/images/ayaka.jpeg'),
      ],
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              CarouselSlider.builder(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  aspectRatio: 1.8,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8,
                  autoPlay: false,
                  initialPage: 0,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason){
                    setState(() {
                      _activeIndex = index;
                    });
                  }
                ),
                itemCount: _images.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(BlackScreen.routeName, (route) => false);
                    },
                      child: _images[index]);
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 565.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: buildIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/Title.svg'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,),
          TabBar(
            indicator: CircleTabIndicator(color: Colors.redAccent, radius: 3),
              tabs: [
                Tab(child: Text('All',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),),),
                Tab(child: Text('Apparel',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),),),
                Tab(child: Text('Dress',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),),),
                Tab(child: Text('Tshirt',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),),),
                Tab(child: Text('Bag',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600),),),
              ]
          ),

          Container(
            height: 60,
            child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  All(items: _items),
                  Center(child: Text('Apparel'),),
                  Center(child: Text('Dress'),),
                  Center(child: Text('Tshirt'),),
                  Center(child: Text('Bag'),),
                ]
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

i finally passed it to the 'All class'

```
class All extends StatelessWidget {
  final List items;
  const All({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
         return Text(items[index]['name']);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not responding"?

Comment: please add the error you are getting

Comment: As first issue i'm seeing that you aren't calling readJson method anywhere and it is returning void. i.e you should change the return type of readJson to Future<Map<String, dynamic>> and return data = await json.decode(response); and in initState method you can do so readJson.then((value) => _items = value); and you should change the type of _items to Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: that is the problem. it is not displaying any errors. it is just not responding. i tried to call 'names' from the json and it is giving me nothing

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you should change the type of your `_list` variable to `Map<String,dynamic>`

And change `readJson` method  return type

```
  Future<Map<String,dynamic>> readJson() async{
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/model/clothes.json');
    return await json.decode(response);
  }
```

And call `readJson` in `initState` like so

```
 @override
  void initState() {
     WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
         readJson().then((value) =>_items = value);
     });
    super.initState();
  }
```

This should do the trick